# What is this light-emitting component?

Tags: led

Can anyone identify this component?  It came from a small night-light, which plugged into a wall outlet (US 120 v ac).  There were no resistors, nor was there any rectifier.  It lights up when plugged in, and it claims to consume 0.05w.
It is shown with a pencil for scale, and it made of some kind of thin film.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like and EL panel.  EL= **E**lectro**L**uminescent.
They glow when they have a sufficient electric potential across them.  They do not consume much power, as they act like a capacitor.  Your's may have a built in diode, or they are just relying on the small capacitance to not pass much current.

[EL Panel on Adafruit.com](https://www.adafruit.com/product/625?gclid=CjwKCAiAq8f-BRBtEiwAGr3DgV6S0lkbKkY1jLF_mns5KMMeJsmeFktOZGImDAVwXBf5NkPmnzPH7RoCBg4QAvD_BwE)
[image]